# Prepending line to a file in platform-independent way

Tags: file-io, tcl

Within a Tcl application I need to prepend a line of Javascript code to an existing .js file.  I googled for "tcl prepend line to file" and didn't find any particularly helpful examples especially in that I need this to be platform-independent.

One approach I found to work is to first open the file for reading, and then for writing, in the following manner:

```
set fileName [file join $appContentDir deleteBinDir.js]
set _fileR [open $fileName r]
set fileContent [read $_fileR]
close $_fileR

set _fileW [open $fileName w]
puts $_fileW "var path = '[file join $appNwDir bin]';\n"
puts $_fileW $fileContent
close $_fileW
```

The resulting Javascript code being:

```
var path = 'C:/opt/dev/dexygen/poc/2eggz/rename_2eggz.vfs/../nw/bin'; //prepended line

var gui = require('nw.gui');
var fs = require('fs');
var p = require("path");

gui.Window.get().on('close', deleteDirectoryContents);

function deleteDirectoryContents() {
    //etc
```

However in one of the results from google search (http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1691902) there was mention of needing to prepend a line to a *large* file in which case I might worry about opening/closing the file twice.  Is there another approach that might work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cut some corners by doing this:

```
set fileName [file join $appContentDir deleteBinDir.js]
set _fileR [open $fileName r+]
set fileContent [read $_fileR]

set preamble "var path = '[file join $appNwDir bin]';\n"
seek $_fileR 0
puts $_fileR $preamble\n$fileContent
close $_fileR
```

or this

```
package require fileutil
set fileName [file join $appContentDir deleteBinDir.js]
set preamble "var path = '[file join $appNwDir bin]';\n"
::fileutil::insertIntoFile $fileName 0 $preamble\n
```

Documentation:
[fileutil (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html)

Answer (score 2):

Using [`fcopy`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/fcopy.htm) might be quicker:

```
file rename file file.orig
set fin [open file.orig r]
set fout [open file w]

puts $fout "first line"
fcopy $fin $fout

close $fin
close $fout
file delete file.orig
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could do this by opening the file in `r+` mode and using seek.  The first three lines of code are essentially the same, but then I stored the line to prepend in a variable.  This allowed me to a) write the line to the first position in the file and b) write the original file contents to the position in the file equating to the length of the line being prepended

```
set fileName [file join $appContentDir deleteBinDir.js]
set _fileR [open $fileName r+]
set fileContent [read $_fileR]

set preamble "var path = '[file join $appNwDir bin]';\n"
seek $_fileR 0
puts $_fileR $preamble

seek $_fileR [string length $preamble]
puts $_fileR $fileContent
close $_fileR
```

The only difference being that there is no second new line after the prepended line, which presumably could be rectified, but functionally makes no difference.

Comment: When overwriting parts of a file, remember that the _byte positions on disk_ of the rest of the file's content don't move.

Comment: @DonalFellows Yes I discovered this on my first naive attempt where I only performed `seek $_fileR 0;puts $_fileR $preamble` and the first several dozen bytes of my file disappeared.  That's when I realized I had to subsequently perform `seek $_fileR [string length $preamble]; puts $_fileR $fileContent`